# R: Quick Way to Select cells of a dataframe based on their length

Tags: r, loops, filter, subset

I have a large data frame and i want to subset the dataframe based on the length of the string.

I have character restrictions and an order of preference for each row.

For example:

```
Column1   Column2                Column3             Column4
A1    Hotels in London, UK   Hotels in London        Hotels
```

If len(column2) is < 30 then i want column 2, else if len(column3) <30 then i want column3, else i want column 4.

i.e. My preference is column2 > column3 > column 4 but these are subject to the character limit of 30.

Currently, i have a loop which takes

```
 for(i in 1:nrow(df) {
  if(nchar(df$`C2`[i]) <= 30) {
    df[i]$`selected` <- df`C2`[i]
  } else if(nchar(df$`C3`[i]) <= 30) {
    df$`selected`[i] <- df$`C3`[i]
  } else (nchar(df$`C4[i]) <= 30) {
     df$`selected`[i]<- df$`C4`[i]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `case_when` in `dplyr` to do conditional selection of a certain column.  It is vectorised so should be faster than looping through.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(selected = case_when(nchar(Column2)<30 ~ Column2,
                               nchar(Column2)>30 & nchar(Column3)<30 ~ Column3,
                               nchar(Column2)>30 & nchar(Column3)>30 ~ Column4
                               ))
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work :

```
DF$Selected <- sapply(seq_len(nrow(DF)),
                      function(i) DF[i,which(nchar(DF[i,-1]) <= 30)[1] + 1] )
```

Brief Explanation

For each row index `i` we :

- select the columns values of row `i` (excluding the first column) and we store their `nchar` :
  `nchar(DF[i,-1])`
- take the first index of the previously computed "nchars" which is `<= 30` :
  `which(nchar(DF[i,-1]) <= 30)[1]`
- then we use this index to select the column (we need to add +1 to this index since we didn't consider the first column)
- use `sapply` the previous operations for each `i` in `1:nrow(DF)`* and return a vector that we store into a new column of `DF` called `Select`

(*)

`seq_len(nrow(DF))` is logically equivalent to `1:nrow(DF)` but is safer because if `DF` has no row it will return an empty vector, while `1:nrow(DF)` would return `c(1,0)` (usually creating "odd" results)